# How to make listview with headers and ListTile?

Tags: listview, indexing, flutter, header

I have ListView and need to insert few headers in current position (index).
But if I use  approach from billow ,my index not in order,I  lose 1st and last place from list...

if I add itemCount: _list.length + 1, and latter index -= 1; I got first section right but that not working for next header..

```
class CheckList extends StatefulWidget {
  bool isCheck = false; //for checkbox
  final String value; //geting value from other class
  List<String> _list = [];

  final List<ListItem> items;

  CheckList({Key key, this.value, this.items}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _Question createState() => _Question();
}

class _Question extends State<CheckList> {
  BuildContext context;


  _getFromDB() async {
    widget._list = await DB().get2(widget.value, 'Description');

    widget._list.insert(0, "Part 1:...");
    widget._list.insert(18, "Part 2:...");
    widget._list.insert(49, "Part 3:...");

    final List<ListItem> items = widget._list.map((value) {
      final index = widget._list.indexOf(value);
      if ([0, 18, 49].contains(index)) {
        return HeaderItem(value);
      } else {
        return MessageItem(value);
      }
    }).toList();

    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    this.context = context;

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            'TITLE APP',
          ),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: getListView(), //listview populated from db
        ));
  }

  Widget getListView() {
    _getFromDB();
    var listview = ListView.builder(
      itemCount: widget.items.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final item = widget.items[index];
        if (item is HeaderItem) {
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                item.heading,
              ),
              Divider(),
            ],
          );
        } else if (item is MessageItem) {
          return ListTile(
            dense: true,
            leading: Checkbox(
              value: item.checked,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  item.checked = value;
                });
              },
            ),
            title: Text(
              item.title,
            ),
            // subtitle: Text(_list2[index]),
          );
        }
      },
    );

    return listview;
  }
}

abstract class ListItem {}

class HeaderItem implements ListItem {
  final String heading;

  HeaderItem(this.heading);
}

class MessageItem implements ListItem {
  final String title;
  bool checked = false;

  MessageItem(this.title);
}
```

So how to correct index nubers and show all items from list with inserted headers..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/mixed-list) approach...

Create classes that will represent different item types (`HeaderItem`,`MessageItem`), then map `_list` to list of items (you will need to have header values inside your `_list`! - for example you can do `_list.insert(18, "Part 2:...")`) and finally use `ListView.builder`.

**Full example:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  final _list = List<String>.generate(100, (index) => "$index");

  _list.insert(0, "Part 1:...");
  _list.insert(18, "Part 2:...");
  _list.insert(49, "Part 3:...");

  final List<ListItem> items = _list.map((value) {
    final index = _list.indexOf(value);
    if ([0, 18, 49].contains(index)) {
      return HeaderItem(value);
    } else {
      return MessageItem(value);
    }
  }).toList();

  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: App(items: items),
    ),
  );
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<ListItem> items;

  const App({Key key, this.items}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final item = items[index];

          if (item is HeaderItem) {
            return Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  item.heading,
                ),
                Divider(),
              ],
            );
          } else if (item is MessageItem) {
            return ListTile(
              leading: Text('$index'),
              title: Text(
                item.title,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

abstract class ListItem {}

class HeaderItem implements ListItem {
  final String heading;

  HeaderItem(this.heading);
}

class MessageItem implements ListItem {
  final String title;

  MessageItem(this.title);
}
```

**Example with checkboxes:**

`App` is now `StatefulWidget`, `MessageItem` has `checked` property.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  final _list = List<String>.generate(100, (index) => "$index");

  _list.insert(0, "Part 1:...");
  _list.insert(18, "Part 2:...");
  _list.insert(49, "Part 3:...");

  final List<ListItem> items = _list.map((value) {
    final index = _list.indexOf(value);
    if ([0, 18, 49].contains(index)) {
      return HeaderItem(value);
    } else {
      return MessageItem(value);
    }
  }).toList();

  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: App(items: items),
    ),
  );
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<ListItem> items;

  const App({Key key, this.items}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: widget.items.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final item = widget.items[index];

          if (item is HeaderItem) {
            return Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  item.heading,
                ),
                Divider(),
              ],
            );
          } else if (item is MessageItem) {
            return ListTile(
              leading: Text('$index'),
              title: Text(
                item.title,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
              ),
              trailing: Checkbox(
                value: item.checked,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    item.checked = value;
                  });
                },
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

abstract class ListItem {}

class HeaderItem implements ListItem {
  final String heading;

  HeaderItem(this.heading);
}

class MessageItem implements ListItem {
  final String title;
  bool checked = false;

  MessageItem(this.title);
}
```

Comment: My _list coming from db, and do you know how to include checkbox in this listview. tnx

Comment: you can do `_list.insert(18, "Part 2:...")` and then map it to list of items. About checkbox: you can add `trailing: Checkbox()` to `ListTile` or use [CheckboxListTile](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CheckboxListTile-class.html).

Comment: @StopicApps Sorry, I didn't notice. I added full example to my answer.

Comment: Thank you, if i use trailing: CheckBox in ListTile , how to distinct checkboxes, if i check one all of them are checked. I know i need to map them but dont know how. tnx

Comment: @StopicApps each checkbox needs to have its own value. For example you can add property `checked` to `MessageItem`. I added example with checkboxes to my answer.

Comment: Hey ,tnx so much, your example working as intended, but im having trouble incorporating in my app, dont know where to put code from your main() cos im already in other class, `class CheckList extends StatefulWidget {
CheckList({Key key, this.value, this.items}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _Question createState() => _Question();
}

class _Question extends State<CheckList> {
...

}

abstract class ListItem {}
...
`

Comment: janstol my man, I edited first post with my current code, can you point me where to insert your parts of code in my code. tnx again.

Comment: @StopicApps I think you can put `_list.insert`s and `_list.map` into your `_getFromDB()` method.

Comment: Tnx,I updated first question post, so the problem is "items" from _getFromDB() not called anywhere.. how to pass that list to  final List<ListItem> items;

Comment: Lets forget about headers for now can you help me just with check boxes in my example from original post thnak you.

Comment: First of all, `items` list is null (`items` in `CheckList` and `items` in `_getFromDB()` are two different lists). Another problem is that you are calling `_getFromDB()` inside build method. So when you tap checkbox, `setState` is called and build method is called which means the `_getFromDB()` method is called with new data. Original question was answered and i don't want to clutter my answer, so i shared fixed code [there](https://privatebin.net/?df3ce40dfb4f0f68#64H3WNf6zg3Gy5scEN4xKm2GLBdZytfKw7Y6N43ecMDM).

Comment: Wow man I can't thank you enough ,I'm new to Dart/Flutter and my confusion is crazy, Ok thing are working now just 
one thing im getting "This function has a return type of 'Widget',but doesn't end with a return statement..." Warning should I suppress or there is other solution.
Thanks again my code was a mess, one more question I suppose I can switch header position as I load new data (query) (should I instantiate ints from _getFromDB() method?
Nwm if I bother you to much on this you already helped me so much, if I can repay you somehow tell me cheers.